# Sencha Touch 2 : Webstorm Run configuration

Tags: sencha-touch-2, webstorm

I am new to Sencha Touch and working on Ubuntu. Till now i followed the instructions from the Sencha Doc and successfully installed Touch 2.2.1 and SenchaCmd.
 I have created a sample project "MyApp" and its in the directory "/var/www/MyApp".
The sdk "touch 2.2.1" is in the same directory "/var/www/touch 2.2.1" 
I am having problem running the code from Webstorm directly in the browser. Can anyone tell the configuration i need to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open your MyApp folder in Webstorm
- create a new JavaScript Debug run configuration like the following:

  1. set URL to `'http://localhost/MyApp/index.html'`
  2. in the 'Remote URLs of local files' field, click twice on 'Remote URL' filed of the topmost tree node (your project root), enter the following URL: `'http://localhost/MyApp'`

that's all... Now on pressing Debug the start page of your application will be loaded into Chrome

Comment: Ok , i did that but my run button is still disabled. Any idea ?

Comment: Button disabled? You must have changed the default run configuration instead of creating your own then. Default configuration is just a template for creating new configurations, it can't itself be executed. Please make sure to add a new configuration using '+' (Alt+Insert) and modify it accordingly

Comment: Yes i did change the default configuration since i didn't knew how to run the application but now i don't know how to reset it to default.Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Solved. In addition to above defined steps , you also need to add the "JetBrains IDE Support" extension in the chrome.